# fetch the records depending on the recent month and year entered

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to fetch the records from the database depending on the recent month and year entered in the table.There are columns in a table displaying the months and year of the records as Month and Year.The below is the sp i have used but its only fetching the records in desc order.I want all the records of the recent month and year only from the database.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_GetComplianceClientIDBy_ProfileID]
    @ProfileID varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --Client Wise for the Currenct Month
select * into  #Client_Business_Mapping 
from TLConnectMasterDB.dbo.Client_Business_Mapping with(nolock) 
where CBM_CNM_ID=@profileID
select ClientID,CM_ClientName, SM.SM_Name as StateName, 
   LM.LM_Name as LocationName,CLM.CL_BranchName as BranchName,
   ROUND(convert(float,sum(CompliedNo)*100/convert(float, 
   (sum(CompliedNo)+sum(NotCompliedNo)))),2) Compliance,
   Round(convert(float,sum(NotCompliedNo)*100/convert(float,
  (sum(CompliedNo)+sum(NotCompliedNo)))),2) NotCompliance 
FROM RegulatoryDB..Monthly_Compliance_Summary MS WITH(NOLOCK)
   join #Client_Business_Mapping 
      on CBM_Client_ID=ClientID collate database_default
   join RegulatoryDB..Clients_Master CM with(nolock)  
      on CM_ClientID=CBM_Client_ID collate database_default
   join RegulatoryDB..Client_LocationMaster CLM with(nolock) 
      on CLM.CL_ClientID = CM.CM_ClientID 
          and MS.State = CLM.CL_StateID 
          and MS.Location = CLM.CL_CityID 
          and MS.Branch=CLM.CL_BranchName
   join RegulatoryDB..State_Master SM 
      on SM.SM_Code=CLM.CL_StateID
   join RegulatoryDb..Location_Master LM 
      on SM.SM_Code=LM.SM_Code and LM.LM_Code=CLM.CL_CityID
where CBM_CNM_ID=@ProfileID 
group by month, Year, ClientID, CM_ClientName, SM.SM_Name, 
   LM.LM_Name, CLM.CL_BranchName
Order by cast(Year as int) desc, cast(Month as int) desc
END
```

Comment: Which database are you using MySQL or SQL-Server ?

Comment: sql server using.

Comment: Then don´t use the mysql tag please

Answer (score 0):

Just add additional predicates to your where clause:

```
where CBM_CNM_ID=@ProfileID 
   and Month = Month(DateAdd(month, -1, getDate())) -- month for 1 month ago
   and Year = Year(DateAdd(month, -1, getDate()))  -- year for 1 month ago
```

but better would be to add a computed column to your table that has the calendar month in it (why are you storing the parts in separate columns in the first place?)

```
Alter table <table with month, year columns>
   Add SummaryDate As DATEFROMPARTS(year, month, 1)
```

then you could just add a where clause predicate that returns all summary rows on or after any specified date:

```
where CBM_CNM_ID=@ProfileID 
   and SummaryDate >= @thresholDate
```

Comment: i guess it is for previous month records and not for most recent month records.

Comment: I cannot alter table.

Comment: If it's for a specific previous month, then just add month, year predicates explicitly as parameters.